# Adaptive Parallel Payment with REST API Example?

Tags: paypal

I didn't quite understand is it possible to split a payment 
among several merchants using the REST API?

If so can anyone reference to an example (preferably PHP)
Google didn't quite find anything for me on the matter.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

REST does not support the full suite of calls that Classic does. You will have to implement Classic (NVP or SOAP) to get to Adaptive payments, where you can split payments via Chained Payments

This page talks about Chained Payments and all the examples it gives are Classic NVP
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Answer (score 1):

As of this point in time it is not supported to do what you are asking. The options as suggested by others are to use Adaptive Payments or Express Checkout. I tend to prefer the former but to each his own.
Just to quote from their page

> The Adaptive Payments API allows merchants and developers to pay
>   almost anyone and set up automated payments. They can create
>   applications that manage payments, payment preapprovals, and refunds.
>   They can also send money peer-to-peer, split payments in both parallel
>   and chained models, accept guest payments, and schedule disbursements.
>   The Adaptive Payments API works on multiple platforms including the
>   web and mobile environments.

The link is [Adpative Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

After going through the above link and understanding the basics, it should be easy to follow the steps mention  [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/)  as mentioned by the above answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. You would have to use either Adaptive Payments or Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php

use this sdk to integrate paypal adaptive payment.